# how to overside MUI css for selected menu item using sx prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I would like to pass `MenuItemStyle` to the `MenuItem` `sx` prop using:

```
const MenuItemStyle = {
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: `${theme.color.secondaryHover}`,
  },
  '&:selected, &:selected:hover': {
    backgroundColor: `${theme.color.secondaryHover}`,
  },
  '&:focusVisible': {
    backgroundColor: `${theme.color.secondaryHover}`,
  },
}
```

return include

```
<MenuItem key={method} value={method} sx={MenuItemStyle}>
              <Checkbox style={CheckboxStyle} checked={value.indexOf(method) > -1} />
              <ListItemText primary={method} primaryTypographyProps={fontStyle} />
            </MenuItem>
```

I am able to get the hover style to change, but not `selected` or `selected:hover`. Maybe I am using the wrong accessor? I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const MenuItemStyle = {
  '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: ${theme.color.secondaryHover},
  },
  '&.Mui-selected, &.Mui-selected:hover': {
    backgroundColor: ${theme.color.secondaryHover},
  },
  '&:focusVisible': {
    backgroundColor: ${theme.color.secondaryHover},
  },
};
```

If you are using MUI Select, you can use `MenuProps`.

For example:

```
<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select"
  value={age}
  label="Age"
  onChange={handleChange}
  MenuProps={{
    sx: {
      "& .Mui-selected.MuiMenuItem-root": {
        backgroundColor: `cyan`
      },
      "& .MuiMenuItem-root:hover": {
        backgroundColor: `green`
      }
    }
  }}
>
</Select>
```